# Delete hyperlink as well as content from cell

Tags: r, excel, hyperlink, openxlsx

I have an excel sheet which contains a hyperlink. I am editing this excel sheet from R using the [openxlsx](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx) package to read and edit it and to save it afterwards again.

One step involves deleting all data from a certain range:

```
  openxlsx::deleteData(
    wb = wb,
    sheet = sheet,
    cols = dataCols,
    rows = dataRows[1]:max_row,
    gridExpand = TRUE
  )
```

The problem is now, that one cell contains a hyperlink, which stays, but the text is deleted.

How can I delete all hyperlinks in the same range as well?

Comment: Filed an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/452

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the Hyperlink to NULL.
Here is a Documentation-Article about that:

[makeHyperlinkString](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.1.0/topics/makeHyperlinkString)

Comment: You should rather use VBA for manipulating Excel-Files by the way. It's built into Excel by Microsoft just for the purpose of doing exactly that. With VBA things are way easier. :)

Comment: Thanks BlueQuote - but I don't want to use Microsoft products for this because I want to stay in the realm of open source - but that is a different issue. And by the way: I have used VBA, and it was in no way easier.

Comment: This sounds to much like a workaround. I will file a bug report, as the documentation to `deleteData` says that it should "Delete contents and styling from a cell." - and a hyperlink is also content.